# Memory interfacing with 8086: IP/CS pointers in EPROM while RAM addresses start at F0000H

Tags: microprocessor, homework, x86

> Design an interface between 8086 CPU and two chips of 16K x 8 EPROM and
>   two chips of 32K x 8 RAM. Select the starting address of EPROM suitably.
>   The RAM address must start at F0000H.

I have a doubt how RAM address starts at F0000H as the IP and CS pointer will be present in EPROM as it is initialized at FFFF0H.

Comment: *" Please provide the answer to that with valid reasons."* Sorry Harshit, but that is not how this site works. Especially as it is home work you must try to answer the question. We provide hints or Socratese questions. This is my question: what is the address range of two times 16Kx8 EEPROMS?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, could you elaborate?

Comment: One question: is the memory given in kilobits or kilobytes? Other will work, other won't.

Comment: @Justme The "x 8" notation makes it explicit -- we're talking about bytes here.

Comment: @DaveTweed then it is impossible to design a working system. There cannot be 64 kilobytes of RAM at F0000H address, because the CPU boots from FFFF0H. Besides interrupt and exception vectors (division by zero, NMI, software interrupts) are located at 00000H so it would preferably have RAM at 00000H, or at least ROM, to make use of them. There must be an error in the task.

Comment: @Justme: Not impossible, just not as simple as the more obvious choices.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct — you need to have EPROM at locations 0xFFFF0 - 0xFFFFF for system startup. Most systems would simply put the 64k bytes of EPROM starting at 0xF0000, and the 64k bytes of RAM starting  at 0x00000 (where it can be used to hold interrupt vectors, etc.).

But if you really need to have RAM at 0xF0000, then you're going to have to be clever about your decoding so that the last 16 bytes show up as EPROM — or at least, immediately following reset.